# Why can't this global function access my global object?

Tags: php, global-variables

This is the code, in global scope:

```
try {
    $Core = new Core;
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'We\'re Sorry, but an error has occurred: <br /> '.$e. "\n";
}

function PP($Object){
    global $Core;
    echo '<pre>'.$Core->Tools()->DebugPrint($Object).'</pre>';
}
```

And I get:

```
Call to a member function Tools() on a non-object
```

This makes no sense. Why can't the `PP` function access the global `$Core` object?

Comment: Where do you define the $Core object?

Comment: @cyber_rookie see second line of code..

Comment: The only explanation is "This is the code, in global scope:" -- that it's not in the global scope

Comment: That's the whole file that is accessed directly in the browser, index.php. It would have to be global scope.

Comment: Obviously it's not the whole source (as there is no function call). You may have overwritten the $Core variable before calling the function, or you may call it from elsewhere, or the file may be included in a function, and the $Core variable will not be global in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

The source above is the entire contents of the index.php file, loaded directly in the browser. There is certainly more code, but the code above is absolutely in the global scope. Also, no other code runs in the global scope so Core could not be overridden.

The Core object constructor begins the application execution and calls other core methods, which call other methods, auto-load classes, use classes etc. But, since the call to PP() inside one of the classes occurs before the completion of the Core constructor, the Core object stays null until the constructor finishes executing (which only occurs when the application is completely finished). The fix to this problem was to  move all of the Core class's initialization out of the constructor, and into an init() method.

This allows the Core to be fully created (using an empty constructor) so the variable is not null when the function tries to execute it, now within the scope of Init() and no longer in __construct().

The new code:

```
try{
   $Core = new Core;
   $Core->Init();
}
catch(Exception $e){
   echo 'We\'re Sorry, but an error has occured: <br /> '. $e. "\n";
}


function PP($Object){
   global $Core;
   echo '<pre>'.$Core->Tools()->DebugPrint($Object).'</pre>';
}
```